# Force update UIViewController from another one after transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am implementing an iOS application which uses [SideMenuController](https://github.com/teodorpatras/SideMenuController) to display the side menu. When a menu button is pushed, the central controller is moved to the side with transition and the side panel is shown.

The issue is that I need to draw an semi-transparent overlay on the remaining central controller. When the side panel is shown the protocol delegate function `sideMenuControllerDidReveal` is called. If I try to add the subview or anyhow change the central view controller's properties, it doesn't take effect until the side panel is hidden and the central view controller becomes central again.

```
public func sideMenuControllerDidReveal(_ sideMenuController: SideMenuController) {
    let coverView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    coverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
    sideMenuController.centerViewController.view.addSubview(coverView)
    sideMenuController.centerViewController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

I am trying to force the UI update with `view.setNeedsDisplay()` but the UI still doesn't get updated.

What is blocking the view from getting updated?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `layoutIfNeeded()` instead of `setNeedsDisplay()` which only schedules a redraw (it doesn't force one).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, anyway I have tried layoutIfNeeded() and setNeedsLayout() but it didn't help.